# Does MadLib support PostgreSQL 9.5 on Mac OSX?

Tags: madlib

I've tried to install with homebrew, and with other instructions... They don't work for postgres 9.4 or 9.5, and leave me with an error like this:

/pgdata95$ /usr/local/bin/madpack -p postgres -c db@localhost/mad install
madpack.py : INFO : Detected PostgreSQL version 9.4.
madpack.py : ERROR : This version is not among the PostgreSQL versions for which MADlib support files have been installed ().

I'm compiling from source to see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the question.  MADlib has been certified on PostgreSQL 9.4.  The current platform support is:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MADLIB/FAQ#FAQ-Q1-2WhatplatformsdoesMADlibsupport?

For quick install instructions, please refer to
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MADLIB/Installation+Guide

Please let us know if you have any other questions.

Frank

Comment: Thanks Frank. I ended up getting it working on an ubuntu vagrant VM with PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: You are welcome.  PostgreSQL 9.5 support will be done in the near term as well.